# Why is one of my NSTimer messing up my background movement?

Tags: ios, ios7, nstimer

I have two NSTimer. The problem is that my countdown timer messes up my background positioning as soon as the countdown timer stops. The background moves properly up until the point where the background timer stops. Then it will automatically reposition the background to the starting position, which I do not want because it seems glitchy when it happens. I want it to keep flowing smoothly as soon as the countdown timer stops. If I were to take the countdown timer out, the background movement works perfectly. Here is my code:

**PlayViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PlayViewController : UIViewController
{
    int countdownStatus;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *background;
    NSTimer *backgroundMovement;
    NSTimer *gameCountdownTimer;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *countdownLabel;

- (void)backgroundMoving;
- (void)gameCountdown;

@end
```

**PlayViewController.m**

```
#import "PlayViewController.h"

@interface PlayViewController ()

@end

@implementation PlayViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.countdownLabel.text = @"3";
    countdownStatus = 2;
    gameCountdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(gameCountdown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    backgroundMovement = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01f target:self selector:@selector(backgroundMoving) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)backgroundMoving
{
    background.center = CGPointMake(background.center.x - 1, background.center.y);
    CGRect backgroundFrame = background.frame;

    if(backgroundFrame.origin.x < -370)
    {
        CGRect myFrame = background.frame;
        myFrame.origin.x = 0;
        myFrame.origin.y = 0;
        background.frame = myFrame;
    }
}

- (void)gameCountdown
{
    if(countdownStatus == 2)
        self.countdownLabel.text = @"2";

    else if(countdownStatus == 1)
        self.countdownLabel.text = @"1";

    else
        self.countdownLabel.text = @"";

    countdownStatus--;
}

@end
```

Comment: are you using autolayout? if so you may be fighting with it.

Comment: Assuming that the `backgroundFrame.origin.x` starts at 0, the `backgroundMoving` method will jump the background back to its original position after 3.7 seconds.  The countdown timer has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Why is it jumping back to the original position after 3.7 seconds? And how can I get around that? Thank you.

Comment: Because the code says `if ( frame.x < -370 ) frame.x = 0;`

Comment: But even when the countdown ends, backgroundFrame.origin.x is always at -300 (not less than -370) so I am still confused as to why it is resetting the position of the background after the countdown ends. I checked to see if it is even hitting that if statement, and it is not. I don't think that is the problem :S

Comment: Still looking for an answer :(